# Google Places API (Android) INVALID_REQUEST - am I missing something?

Tags: android, google-places-api

I'm working with Places API and I'm getting INVALID_REQUEST when I try to check for nearby places. Here's a snippet of my code - is there anything wrong with this? Am I missing something?

```
        urlString.append("&location=");
        urlString.append(Double.toString(latitude));
        urlString.append(",");
        urlString.append(Double.toString(longitude));
        urlString.append("&rankby=distance");
        urlString.append("&types="+place);
        urlString.append("&sensor=false&key=" + API_KEY);
```

'place' is a string fed into this method.

Answer (score 0):

Hi
Since you only posted this, you should check the **place** String and see if it's supported  [Google Places API Types Supported](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types), you probably misspelled it, remember to use the singular not the plural.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to try a library that provides a Java interface to the Google Places API, you could take a look at [Sprockets](https://github.com/pushbit/sprockets-android) (disclosure: I'm the developer).  It allows you to query like below, so you don't have to worry about URLs, query strings, and JSON responses.

```
List<Place> places = Places.nearbySearch(Params.create()
        .latitude(47.60567).longitude(-122.3315).radius(5000)
        .keyword("swimming").openNow(true).maxResults(5)).getResult();
```

See the [Places](https://pushbit.github.io/sprockets/apidocs/index.html?net/sf/sprockets/google/Places.html) class for all of the possible requests and their details.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't mention the output, you are probably missing the *[output](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchRequests)*  in the url.

```
urlString.append("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/")
urlString.append("json?")
urlString.append("location=");
urlString.append(Double.toString(latitude));
urlString.append(",");
urlString.append(Double.toString(longitude));
urlString.append("&rankby=distance");
urlString.append("&types="+place);
urlString.append("&sensor=false&key=" + API_KEY);
```

and the `&` before location is obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

in my case my URL was incorrect, I had placed a `$` sign instead of `&`.